# totaling hours by month for split weeks using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I am trying to total hours for an entire year by month.
However, I have come accross an issue for months that end and start in the middle of the week.
Here is my solution however, i had to hardcode the linq to work for this particular week date.
In this example the

```
 WeekStart is Febuary 26 2012 - SUNDAY
    WeekEnd is March 1 2012 - THURSDAY
```

Now in my hardcoded example
when it is a normal week this is used (refer to sumval)

```
.ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.TOTALHOURS).Value;
```

when it is a split week for the next month it will use (refer to sumval1)

```
.ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.THURSDAY + y.FRIDAY + y.SATURDAY).Value;
```

when it is a split week for the previous month (refer to sumval2)

```
.ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.SUNDAY + y.MONDAY + y.TUESDAY + y.WEDNESDAY).Value;
```

Based on these the hours will be charged to the proper month on weeks that are split between twon months.

problem is i dont want to hard code these days of the week, how can i dynamically populate the days that should be added for sumval1 and sumval2

```
  double sumval =    data.Where(x => 
    //ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(x.WKENDDATE, x.WKENDDATE.AddDays(6)) != true &&
    x.PORTFOLIO.ToUpper() == item.portfolio.ToUpper() &&
    x.PHASE.ToUpper() == portitem.phase.ToUpper() && 
    x.PHASEDESCRIPTION.ToUpper() == portitem.phasedesc.ToUpper() && 
    x.WKENDDATE.ToString("MMM yyyy").ToUpper() == monitem.monthname.ToString() 
   .ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.TOTALHOURS).Value;


  double sumval1 =
       data.Where(x =>
       ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(x.WKENDDATE, x.WKENDDATE.AddDays(6)) == true &&
       x.PORTFOLIO.ToUpper() == item.portfolio.ToUpper() &&
       x.PHASE.ToUpper() == portitem.phase.ToUpper() &&
       x.PHASEDESCRIPTION.ToUpper() == portitem.phasedesc.ToUpper() &&
       ExportHelper.getSplitEndDate(x.WKENDDATE).AddDays(1).ToString("MMM yyyy").ToUpper() == monitem.monthname.ToString()
      .ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.THURSDAY + y.FRIDAY + y.SATURDAY).Value;



  double sumval2 =
      data.Where(x =>
      ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(x.WKENDDATE, x.WKENDDATE.AddDays(6)) == true &&
      x.PORTFOLIO.ToUpper() == item.portfolio.ToUpper() &&
      x.PHASE.ToUpper() == portitem.phase.ToUpper() &&
      x.PHASEDESCRIPTION.ToUpper() == portitem.phasedesc.ToUpper() &&
      x.WKENDDATE.ToString("MMM yyyy").ToUpper() == monitem.monthname.ToString()
     .ToUpper()).Sum(y => y.SUNDAY + y.MONDAY + y.TUESDAY + y.WEDNESDAY).Value;
```

Comment: Can you include a few sample data points so we can see what `data` looks like? What fields it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could be better off putting your data into a custom class that is more representative of how you want to view the data. I'm assuming the data is on a weekly basis, given that you're doing comparisons on week end dates and accessing properties for each day of the week.

Given that, I would suggest transforming whatever type `data` is to something at a daily level, with actual `datetime` representations for each day. Assuming you create a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    DateTime Date {get;set;}
    int Val {get;set;}
    ... //other properties
}
```

you can transform one record in `data` into an bunch of instances of `MyClass` like this (assuming `WKENDDATE` represents a Saturday):

```
List<MyClass> transformed = new List<MyClass>
foreach(var item in data)
{
    var sunday = new MyClass{Date = item.WKENDDATE.AddDays(-6), Val = item.SUNDAY};
    var monday = new MyClass{Date = item.WKENDDATE.AddDays(-5), Val = item.MONDAY};
    ...
    transformed.Add(sunday);
    transformed.Add(monday);
    ...
}
```

Once you have your data in this form, summing by month is trivial:

```
int month = 1; 
int year = 2012; 
var jan2012 = transformed.Where(x => x.Date.Month == month && x.Date.Year == year).Sum(x=>x.Val);
```

Comment: The names `MyClass`, `Date`, and `Val` leave something to be desired.  If you're going to recommend a specific class for a specific problem, pick a real name and not a placeholder.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: If there was a more solid context given in the question as to what the data contains maybe I would have used suitable names. Generally, IMO, questions like this are more about guiding to a possible solution than worrying about good names and perfect coding standards. But when you see something that bothers you in the future, just edit it.